# Search/check values in YAML document with Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

**my goal:**

check if yaml document include value for specific key using ypath/xpath

select value for specified key using ypath/xpath

**document yaml**:

```
app:
    name: xxx
    version: xxx
description:
    author:
        name: xxx
        surname: xxx
        email: xxx@xxx.xx
```

**what was checked:***

google

stackoverflow

Ruby API (YAML::DBM as one of methods it provide is *select*)

**example:**

```
Module::Class.select('description/author/name')
Module::Class.select('*/name')
Module::Class.isset?('*/name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no up-to-date YPath implementations around, I would suggest to give a chance `ActiveSupport` and `Nokogiri`:

```
yml = LOAD_YML_WITH_YOUR_PREFERRED_YAML_ENGINE

# ActiveSupport adds a to_xml method to Hash
xml = yml.to_xml(:root => 'yaml')

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.xpath("description/author/name").map do |name|
  puts [name['key'], name['value']]
end
```

Comment: Yeap, w can't use YPath. I've tried to use YAML/Psych::DBM without luck. I've ended using XML instead of YAML with Nokogiri gem. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Use yaml:

```
require 'yaml'
yml = YAML.load_file('your_file.yml')
```

Now yml is a hash. You can use it like one. Here is a simple and ugly solution for what you try:

```
if !yml["description"].nil? && !yml["description"]["author"].nil? && !yml["description"]["author"]["name"].nil? && !yml["description"]["author"]["name"].empty?
  puts "An author is set!"
end
```

Comment: Hello, thx for response, but it's not what i meant, I've updated My Goal section in question. BR.

Comment: Sorry link to the wrong answer. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9977987/812912

Comment: Yeap i saw that also, but problem is that there is no example attached  in that pdf.

Comment: have you seen the rdoc the user refers to?

Comment: Of course, but unfortunately it is not well documented in manner of example (working thing). Unless somebody already worked with ypath in Ruby YAML i will have to dig more and try to find proper way... but i would rather not invent wheel from beginning :)